# Importing Stored Procedure into edmx

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, db2

I'm using Entity Framework with IBM DB2 Data provider and i want to import stored procedures into my edmx file.

[image]

but after selecting the stored procedures that i want to include from DB2 database, nothing is showing up in the Model browser

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Gowrish.

Comment: I can able to import and use Tables successfully but not the stored procedures :(

Comment: Is there any message from the output when trying to import the SP?

Comment: No error and i dont see any changes in the edmx file xml and I think that this is only happen with IBM DB2 databases...When i tried with SQL it does imports and showing up in Model browser

Comment: A quick google search on the subject gave me... this question. You might look into manually adding the procedure instead of using the designer.